# Receiving only serial data in the power of 2 when sending the alphabeth

Tags: encoding, bluetooth, arduino, serial-port

I am trying to perform a simple experiment with an Arduino Uno and the [BlueSmirf Bluetooth](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/using-the-bluesmirf) module from Sparkfun ([documentation](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/1/e/e/5/d/5217b297757b7fd3748b4567.pdf)).

My hardware setup looks like this:

```
Arduino(power through USB)->BlueSmirf     ---(bluetooth)-->    PC(no wired connection the the Arduino)->RealTerm
```

On the Arduino, the following sketch is running:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

int txPin = 2;
int rxPin = 3;

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(txPin, rxPin);

void setup() {
    bluetooth.begin(115200);
    delay(100);
}

void loop() {
    String textToSend = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw123456789";
    bluetooth.print(textToSend);
    delay(5000);
}
```

Now, the bluetooth connects to the PC just fine, but when I inspect the COM port in RealTerm, I only get the following output:

```
abdhp1248
```

Where did the remaining letters and numbers go? It seems like all of the letters that follow the power of two, (i.e. a=1, b=2, d=4, h=8, p=16) print, but none of the rest. Is this just a coincidence?

Comment: Try reducing the baud rate to something like 9600, you might be overflowing a buffer somewhere.  ie. bluetooth.begin(9600);

Comment: @TomKeddie, you could be right. I did try to run it at 9600, but now with the current test string. I will do that and se what I get.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're running the serial port too fast.  As per the comments in the sparkfun BlueSmirf example at https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/using-the-bluesmirf - "115200 can be too fast at times for NewSoftSerial to relay the data reliably".

Reduce the baud rate to 9600 using the code example below, modified from the above web page.

```
/*
  Example Bluetooth Serial Passthrough Sketch
 by: Jim Lindblom
 SparkFun Electronics
 date: February 26, 2013
 license: Public domain

 This example sketch converts an RN-42 bluetooth module to
 communicate at 9600 bps (from 115200), and passes any serial
 data between Serial Monitor and bluetooth module.
 */
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>  

int bluetoothTx = 2;  // TX-O pin of bluetooth mate, Arduino D2
int bluetoothRx = 3;  // RX-I pin of bluetooth mate, Arduino D3

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);

void setup()
{

  bluetooth.begin(115200);  // The Bluetooth Mate defaults to 115200bps
  bluetooth.print("$");  // Print three times individually
  bluetooth.print("$");
  bluetooth.print("$");  // Enter command mode
  delay(100);  // Short delay, wait for the Mate to send back CMD
  bluetooth.println("U,9600,N");  // Temporarily Change the baudrate to 9600, no parity
  // 115200 can be too fast at times for NewSoftSerial to relay the data reliably
  bluetooth.begin(9600);  // Start bluetooth serial at 9600
}

void loop()
{
    String textToSend = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw123456789";
    bluetooth.print(textToSend);
    delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Tom! I have given this sketch another roll, and tried changing up a few things during the debugging of it. It turns out that the point of failure for this sketch is the "bluetooth.begin(9600)" - the second time Software.Serial is set - that breaks it all. I manage to communicate with the modem at baud 115200 (getting the strange behaviour above), but when I switch to baud 9600, the connection between the arduino and modem goes absolutely dead. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry Tormod, don't have any ideas for you - except maybe to call bluetooth.end() before calling begin() a second time?

Comment: That's actually a pretty good idea. I will give it a try. Thanks. :-)